# Can i retrieve Youtube Analytics data without using OAuth 2.0 (PHP)?

Tags: php, youtube, google-analytics, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

Is it possible to  retrieve youtube analytic data **without using OAuth** . instead can i get data using a Server key??

I want all data .

Is it possible???
I have tried OAuth, but for every account a annoying pop-out comes. i want to get rid of it. i wanted to know if i can make cron job by which i can retrieve and store in database.

Answer (score 3):

I think the current version of the API requires OAuth authorization, but that doesn't mean you have to authorize in the browser every time.

You can either use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount), which allows your application to authorize itself without your intervention or use web application authorization and store the token in a database so the app can use it to authenticate itself later without your intervention.